# Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED in react with spotify api

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, connection

im trying to build an spotify clone that uses spotify api. Basically im getting this error everytime i try to get the authorization code, does anyone know how to fix that? This code is from a video in youtube, but he didn't had this problem, i think that maybe is something with windows defender or something blocking the connection. Also the app is divided in client-side and server-side, both running separately.

Error:

[image: Link to image error]

This is my server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const SpotifyWebApi = require('spotify-web-api-node')
const cors = require('cors')
const app = express();
app.use(cors())
app.use(express.json())

app.post('/login', (req, res) => { 
    const code = req.body.code;
    const spotifyApi = new SpotifyWebApi({
        redirectUri: 'http://localhost:3000/',
        clientId: '',
        clientSecret: ''
    })

    spotifyApi
    .authorizationCodeGrant(code)
    .then(data => {
        res.json({
            accessToken: data.body.access_token,
            refreshToken: data.body.refresh_token,
            expiresIn: data.body.expires_in
        })
    }).catch(err => {
        res.sendStatus(400)
    })
    app.listen(3001)
})
```

This is my auth hook, its basically doing all the authentication part

```
import {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'

export default function useAuth(code) {
    const [accessToken, setAccessToken] = useState()
    const [refreshToken, setRefreshToken] = useState()
    const [expiresIn, setExpiresIn] = useState()

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.post('http://localhost:3001/login',{
        code,
        })
        .then(res =>{
        console.log(res.data)
        setAccessToken(res.data.accessToken)
        setRefreshToken(res.data.refreshToken)
        setExpiresIn(res.data.expiresIn)
        window.history.pushState({}, null, '/')
        })
        .catch((err) =>{
            console.log(err)
            //window.location = '/'
        })
    }, [code])
    useEffect(() =>{

    }, [refreshToken, expiresIn])
    return accessToken
}
```